# How to find first non null value in a typescript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an `arr` variable which looks as below:

```
const arr = [undefined, undefined, 'hello', 'hello', 'hi'];
```

I want to print out the first `non-null` value from within the `arr` array variable.

In above array, the output should be `hello`

I have written following logic but it is not giving the correct result:

```js
const arr = [undefined, undefined, 'hello', 'hello', 'hi'];
const index = arr.length;

while (index-- && !arr[index]);

console.log(arr[index]);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const arr = [undefined, undefined, 'hello', 'hello', 'hi'];

console.log(arr.find(el => el !== undefined))
```

It *returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function*.

Answer (score 7):

```js
const arr = [undefined, null, 'hello', 'hello', 'hi'];

console.log(arr.find(el => el))
// or
console.log(arr.find(el => !!el))
```

Answer (score 4):

Start with initial index as '0'

```js
const arr = [undefined, undefined, 'hello', 'hello', 'hi'];
let index = 0;

while (!arr[index]) index++;

console.log(index, arr[index]);
```

Alternatively, use [`findIndex`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp)

```js
const arr = [undefined, undefined, 'hello', 'hello', 'hi'];

const index = arr.findIndex(val => val);

console.log(index, arr[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the posted answers are incorrect, however you may hit issues if ESLint is configured to watch [arrow-parens](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-parens) (Airbnb rules adhere to this).

If you want to adhere to best practice, utilise one of the below (very minor modification to Psidom and Pavlov's answers).

```js
const arr = [undefined, undefined, 'Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

console.log(arr.find((el) => el));
console.log(arr.find((el) => el !== undefined));
```